# Launch a powershell script in multiple windows with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell

I want to launch a powershell script in multiple windows with multiple parameters

```
foreach($Instance in $config){

    $MaxSamples = $UserInput.MaxSamples
    $SampleInterval = $UserInput.SampleInterval
    $instance = $Instance

        cmd /c start powershell -NoExit -Command {.\sqlcounters.ps1 $instance $SampleInterval $MaxSamples $OutputDirectory $Instance_$MaxSamples_iterations_with_db}

}
```

Could some one sugggest on how to specify the multiple parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Start-Process` cmdlet:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit -File c:\test.ps1",$arg1,$arg2,$arg3
```

Comment: Wohooo Great Shay, Always to the rescue :)